# Javascript efficiency: big object vs many arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, websocket

I'm working on building a little web based game (websockets and nodejs) and I'm just curious on which approach would be considered better practice / more efficient.

I've got a bunch of clients that can connect to the game server. each client has a bunch of different properties that needs to be saved..

- position: x,y,direction,speed,etc.
- attributes: energy, hp, damage, etc.
- websocket connection info
- controls: keypresses, etc
- a couple other things

currently I've divided those areas into separate arrays, so if I need to get the position of user 12 I look at **usrPos[12].x** and if I need to send info to the client through the websocket I look at **usrSoc[12].id** and so forth.

I've been wondering lately if I should have all the info combined into one array. so I look at **usr[12].pos.x** and **usr[12].soc.id**. obviously this creates an array of much bigger objects, but improves readability to some degree. Also I don't need to keep track of 10 different arrays to store data for one user.

So which way is better? is one approach any more efficient then the other? interested to hear what people think. thanks!

Comment: this is way too broad for [so]

Comment: Actually it creates just *more* objects, not *bigger* ones. And in theory both approaches should take about the same amount of space, although [they might have different access characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array). In practise, it really doesn't matter at all; if it does matter enough for you then you should benchmark the solutions against each other on your real data.

Comment: It is almost certain that not splitting logically connected data into different data structures is conceptually easier and less error-prone. E.g. think what you'd need to do if one of the user needs to be deleted in both scenarios; or if users need to be sorted; or if, after you've implemented those things, a new attribute needs to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which way is better? Well, we are talking about basic OOP, here: you have many different "arrays" which contains information about a client, and the information of a client is scattered through many different arrays, and every array must share the index with another 10 arrays.

You have a problem: what happens when you remove a socket from the sockets array, but do not remove the position? BUG!

So, if a client is a client, treat it as a whole, with 10 (in your example) composite properties, about the client's socket, his attributes, etc.

Please, don't think about "efficiency". Your question's answer is not about efficiency, is about maintainability, robustness and simplicity. This things usually drive you naturally toward better performance, but you should care about performance only if you have a performance problem.

Remember (write it down on a wall): [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with (or at least very little to do with) "OOP".

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following you. The first thing one has to do when designing the "classes" in the system is to decide which kinds of objects are involved and what they are about. As I told, basic OOP. If there is a client "thingy", there probably should be a Client class, or at least objects with client attributes, if he's not going to implement a proper class. Not that there is such a thing in JavaScript, but you get the idea, I hope.

Comment: not a big deal, but normally OOP is used to refer to design of classes and class hierarchies which encapsulate data and functionality. This is more a matter of plain old data structure design.

Comment: So basically you're saying it's better to just worry about simplicity. Because even if there is any performance gain to be had, it's probably such a small difference that it never would have affected anything anyways. And wouldn't justify the extra effort.

Comment: Almost. I'm saying that performance must be a concern only when it becomes a concern. Plan first for maintainability (or testability, which is in practice the same) and make the software work. Then, measure. If the measure doesn't satisfy, and only then, you can start optimizing. And only the 10% that is the real bottleneck: quite possibly the performance drains are not where you expect them to be, so measure first and refactor later.